# error installing capybara-webkit. Can not compile

Tags: capybara-webkit

I can not handle the situation to install capybara-webkit on yosemity
Any idea is welcome.

```
Installing capybara-webkit (1.3.1) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/boti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
cd src/ && /usr/local/bin/qmake /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myaidin/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.1/src/webkit_server.pro -spec /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile.webkit_server
cd src/ && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
g++ -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include -Ibuild -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib -x c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server.gch/c++
gcc -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include -Ibuild -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib -x objective-c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server.gch/objective-c++
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:55,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:12,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:80,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include/QtGui/qmacdefines_mac.h:113,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:99,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qapplication.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QApplication:1,
                 from stable.h:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:262: error: expected `}' before ‘__attribute__’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:262: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:414: error: expected `}' before ‘__attribute__’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:414: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:493: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[1]: *** [build/webkit_server.gch/objective-c++] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2
Command 'make' failed

make "DESTDIR="
cd src/ && /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f Makefile.webkit_server 
gcc -pipe -O2 -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Wall -W -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -I. -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/4/Headers -I/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include -Ibuild -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib -x objective-c++-header -c stable.h -o build/webkit_server.gch/objective-c++
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:55,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSURLError.h:12,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:80,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/Cocoa.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include/QtGui/qmacdefines_mac.h:113,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/include/QtGui/qwindowdefs.h:99,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qapplication.h:46,
                 from /usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/QApplication:1,
                 from stable.h:1:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:262: error: expected `}' before ‘__attribute__’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:262: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:414: error: expected `}' before ‘__attribute__’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:414: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Headers/FSEvents.h:493: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[1]: *** [build/webkit_server.gch/objective-c++] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-webkit_server-pro-make_default-ordered] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myaidin/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/boti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@myaidin/gems/capybara-webkit-1.3.1/./gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit (1.3.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.3.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using gcc, which has trouble compiling some of Apple's newer frameworks.

If your `CC` or `CXX` environment variables are set, make sure they're set to `cc` and `c++` and not something like `gcc` and `g++`.